# Who wins two player sudoku?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, surreal-numbers, sudoku

Let's say players take turns placing numbers 1-9 on a sudoku board. They must not create an invalid position (meaning that you can not have the same number in within a row, column, or box region). The first player who can't move loses, and the other player wins.

Given a partially filled sudoku board, what is a way to evaluate the winner (or even better, the nimber) of the position (besides brute force)?

Additionally, has this perhaps been analyzed before?

(A natural generalization is to allow certain players to only play certain digits, in which case each position can be assigned a CGT game value.)

Comment: So invalid as a game move is a proper subset of invalid as a Sudoku puzzle placement (toward a unique solution)?  Gerhard "Wrong Can Mean Many Things" Paseman, 2018.04.14.

Comment: This is a finite game, and so one of the players must have a winning strategy by the fundamental theorem of finite games. Can we mount a strategy-stealing argument to show that it cannot be the second player?

Comment: The question about computing the game value seems clear: this is a finite game and we can in principle compute the entire game tree, and thereby come to know computably the nimber and game value of any given position. The actual question should be not *whether* we can do this (even for arbitrary finite size boards), but rather to find feasible ways to do this.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I clarified the question

Comment: I'm confused here.  Sudoku, _actual Sudoku_ that is trademarked by Nikoli publishing, both must be symmetrical in initial clues and also have only one solution. I'd assume either two players taking turns and timing it, or allow any player to make a move when they find one and then tallying up the number of moves as possible ways to "win" 2p Sudoku.  If a player makes a move where the next player's move is invalid, then the current player's move is also invalid (as it creates an invalid board). Unless, as it appears, you're just filling up a board with numbers 1-9, why is this tagged Sudoku?

Comment: @n_b To my way of thinking, the essence of Sudoku consists of the requirements for a completed solution that every row and column and each of the main $3\times 3$ subsquares should contain all the numbers 1 through 9. (The other "rules" you mention seem less important.) This is a game based fundamentally on those requirements, and so it makes sense to call it the Sudoku game.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman No, just as long as it doesn't violate the normal sudoku constraint.

Comment: So "No" means "No, it is not a proper subset", which means every legal play is part of a valid Sudoku solution, which means the game essentially involves traversing the tree of valid configurations until a single branch is agreed upon (or the whole square is completed). In which case the parity of number of empty squares determines the winner.  Gerhard "Now I Understand Even Less" Paseman, 2018.04.15.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman It does not need to be a solvable position.

Comment: @DukeZhou Oh sorry, didn't see this til now. Unfortunately, the link is dead now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update.** I made a blog post about [Infinite Sudoku and the Sudoku game](http://jdh.hamkins.org/infinite-sudoku-and-the-sudoku-game/), following up on ideas in this post and the comments below.

---

I claim that the second player wins the even-sized empty Sudoku boards and the first player wins for odd-sized empty Sudoku boards, including the main $9\times 9$ case. (The odd-case solution uses a key idea of user orlp in the comments.)

Consider first the even-sized board case, which is a little easier. For example, perhaps we have a board of size $16\times 16$, divided into subsquares of size $4\times 4$. 
[image]

The second player can win in this case by the mirror-play strategy. (This argument was pointed out to me by my daughter, 11 years old.) That is, given any move by the other player, let the second player play the mirror image of that move through the origin. The new play cannot violate the Sudoku condition if the previous play did not, since the new violation would reflect to an earlier violation. The point is that on an even-sized board, the reflection of any row, column or subsquare will be a totally different row, column or subsquare, and so by maintaining symmetry, the second player can ensure that any violation of the Sudoku conditions will arise with the first player.

This copying strategy breaks down on the odd-sized board, however, including the main $9\times 9$ case, since there is a central row and column and a central subsquare and copying a move there would immediately violate the Sudoku conditions.

Nevertheless, user orlp explained in the comments how to adapt the mirroring strategy to the odd case.

Namely, in the main $9\times 9$ case, let's have the first player play a $5$ in the center square, and thereafter play the ten's complement mirror image of the opponent's moves. That is, if opponent played $x$, the first player should play $10-x$ in the mirror location. In this way, the first player can ensure that after her moves, the board is ten's complement symmetric through the origin. This implies that any violation of the Sudoku requirement will reduce by reflection to an earlier violation in the reflected moves, and so it is a winning strategy.

[image]

More generally, in the general odd case $k^2\times k^2$ for $k^2=2n-1$, player one will play $n$ in the middle square, and then proceed to play the $2n$'s complement mirroring move of the opponent. In this way, the first player ensures that after her play, the board remains $2n$'s complement symmetric, and this implies that she will not be the first to violate the Sudoku conditions. So it is a winning strategy.

Notice that in the even case, the second player could also have won by playing the complement mirror strategy, rather than the mirror strategy, since again any violation of the Sudoku condition would reflect to an earlier but complementary violation.

Finally, see my blog post for the winning strategy in the case of the [Infinite Sudoku game](http://jdh.hamkins.org/infinite-sudoku-and-the-sudoku-game/), which came up in the comments.

Comment: I believe you can apply this winning strategy for player 1 on the $9\times 9$ board by first playing $5$ in the center, and then mirroring any move $x$ by player 2 through the center, you playing $10-x$.

Comment: Does it work? I think it works! Let me think about it, and then I'll edit if I agree.

Comment: I interpret partially filled as meaning the starting configuration is not an empty board.  You might want to make clear that this mirror strategy is starting from an empty or a symmetrically filled board.  Gerhard "Make Board And Strategy Clear" Paseman, 2018.04.14.

Comment: Yes, @GerhardPaseman so far, I am considering only the main game, starting from an empty board

Comment: Then I find your main point unclear, as Sudoku solutions aren't necessarily symmetric. (It may hold for the 4by4 board, but I don't see it for the 16by16.) If you know a lot about the graph of configurations, then you might be able to convince me.  Gerhard "It's Really A Graph Traversal" Paseman, 2018.04.14.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What is unclear? In the $16\times 16$ board case, I claim that the winning strategy is for the second player to produce a symmetric board. This is winning, since any violation of the Sudoku requirements will first harm the first player first.

Comment: Short answer: I'm not sure what is wrong. Long answer: my first question remains unanswered, and I suspect your argument fails because the first player can make a move which violates no local conditions but leaves only an even number of moves left, because each play after that violates a local condition (and results in a nonsudoku). I'm willing to play some short games with you to illustrate.  Gerhard "I Will Even Move First" Paseman, 2018.04.14.

Comment: Maybe a bit more explanation is needed for why, in the even case, the 2nd player's reflected move "cannot violate the sudoku condition if the previous play did not." The point (as I see it) is the 2nd player's move is not in the same row, column, or box as the immediately previous move, so it is not under any constraints that didn't also apply to the immediately previous move. (A rigorous proof seems to involve an induction showing both that the 2nd player's moves are legal and that they always leave the board configuration symmetrical.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass If the second player ensures that the board is symmetric, then isn't it clear that any violation of the Sudoku rules existing after her play must have already existed by symmetry at the earlier stage?

Comment: And in the odd-size board case, the argument is similar, with the appropriately modified version of symmetry, to refer to the complementary $2n$'s complement symmetry.

Comment: Yes, it's clear, once you observe that the 2nd player's move is not in the same row, column, or box as the 1st player's immediately previous move. The argument wouldn't work if, instead if symmetry under reflection in the center point, one used symmetry under reflection in the vertical line through the center. Then the 2nd player's move would be in the same row as the 1st player's immediately previous move, and would violate the sudoku condition. So not just any symmetry will do, and my comment intended to indicate why the symmetry you used does work.

Comment: Okay, this solves the empty board. Any idea how to continue with other starting positions? Probably easiest to start with mostly filled boards.

Comment: (And also figuring out the nimber in the odd-sized board case.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I'm sorry, I must've read over that.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: and what happens when the rows and columns of the subsquare are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$? :P

Comment: @SamHopkins Nice idea! In the $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ subsquare case, where the whole board is $\mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathbb{Z}^2$, then the first player can ensure not to lose on her turn: play $0$ in the center of the center board, and afterwards play the negation ($\mathbb{Z}$'s complement) at the mirror location, just as in the odd-size board case. This strategy, however, will not ensure that the final board is filled in, nor that every subsquare, row and column uses all the numbers.

Comment: Why don't you ask it as a separate question? The infinite Sudoku game! I guess it should be like this: players must never violate the local Sudoku conditions, and then player 2 wins, if the final board is a full Sudoku solution. Can player 2 win the $\mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathbb{Z}^2$ case? Or the $\mathbb{N}^2\times\mathbb{N}^2$ case? I guess you could allow play to proceed beyond $\omega$, if the board is not yet filled in. For any infinite linear order $L$, we have the $L^2\times L^2$ game.

Comment: In the infinite case, notice that nobody can ever get stuck: just play always a totally new number. So the game is really about the winning condition that is set at the end after infinite play.

Comment: I guess the *order* doesn't matter; the game is just about the cardinality of the subsquares, with the whole board $\kappa^2\times \kappa^2$ for some cardinal $\kappa$. So the $\mathbb{Z}$ game is isomorphic to the $\mathbb{N}$ game. Is that right?

Comment: @SamHopkins It seems to me that the player trying to make a full solution can do so on any countable board, since any that player can simply play so as to ensure that every number appears on any given row, column and subsquare, and that every square is filled in with something. One can do this compatibly with any given finite legal position. There are countably many requirements in all, and so the player can simply ensure the $n^{th}$ one on the $n^{th}$ move. Thus, player 2 wins the $\mathbb{N}^2\times\mathbb{N}^2$ Sudoku game. A similar argument works for uncountable $\kappa$ with long play.

Comment: Thus, it doesn't even matter who goes first or whether the play starts from a board where finitely many moves have already been made. One can even allow the spoiler player to make finitely many moves at once, and still the Sudoku player can force that it becomes a Sudoku solution.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It's easy to create a position where its impossible to put a number somewhere. For example, put a 5 on a given row, and then fill up a box on that row, leaving open for the 5 only a box on the row with the 5. The puzzle is now unsolvable. The question is whether the solution player can stop this scenario.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have described a strategy that wins for the Sudoku-solver on the infinite board, starting from any legal *finite* position.

Comment: What I'm thinking, is that family game night at the Hamkins household must be pretty fun, what with infinite chess and all.

Comment: @MarkS Oh, yes, it lasts all night! We make popcorn in giant tubs, with the kernels labeled 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Comment: In the infinite Sudoku game, it seems to me that the solver can win from any position that has an extension to a solution, even when the spoiler is allowed to play infinitely many numbers, provided only that they can in principle be extended to a solution. The reason is that she can still arrange to meet the requirements I mentioned earlier, performing the $n^{th}$ one on her $n^{th}$ move. The spoiler cannot spoil the solution only in the limit, if every move is part of an actual solution, even if the solution the spoiler has in mind keeps changing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that betting on your daughter's future success in life is a winning strategy you adopted.

Comment: @Sylvain Indeed, she is a sharp one! She noticed the symmetry strategy immediately after I explained the problem to her. She says that she will either be a mathematician or a philosopher when she grows up, but I think lately it is leaning toward math. Of course, the world of possibility is open to her.

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating this solution!  I can't tell you how grateful I am because it answers a question I've had for a long time.  This is a wonderful primer from someone like myself who has such questions.  I actually found your blog because I was thinking of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300305/how-to-describe-the-common-boundaries-between-regions-in-a-infinite-sudoku) and googled infinite sudoku. Would very much like to know your thoughts!

Comment: It won't let me comment on the voted solution, but does it guarantee that the first player in even or second player in odd can't just play for a draw and complete the whole Sudoku?

Comment: The argument shows that on even boards, the second player can ensure that she is not the one who is left without a move; and similarly on odd boards for the first player. If the losing player plays so as to achieve a suitably symmetric Sudoku solution, then it will be winning player who achieves the solution.

Comment: Here's my question: By constraining the subsets to a finite number of elements, it seems clear that the simple mirroring solution holds for $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$, and that a complementary strategy is required for $(3^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$.  If this is the case, doesn't it suggest an *effect* of the parity of countably infinite sets?  *(I'm trying to formulate a valid question on this topic, but my questions don't do well b/c I lack formal training and like to work things out starting from first principles.  Any assist would be welcome!)*

Comment: (Also note that in this form of infinite sudoku, $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$ & $(3^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$, the regions do seem to connect!)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the form of the 2 player Sudoku game, and whether it's partisan or impartial.

You can [read more about intrinsic partisan Sudoku (m,n,p-games) here.](http://www.mclassgames.com/terminology-m/)

The solutions pointed out by Dr. Hamkins hold for the impartial forms of Sudoku games, but break down in non-reduced partisan forms.

The main distinction of partisan Sudoku is that the elements have value.  We call the form reduced in which the values are binary (think Go and m,n,k-games).  Each element in the Sudoku, regardless of label is either [+1,-1], which corresponds to "two colors" *("U&I", if you'll forgive the pun on Ultraviolet and Infrared;)*

The reduced form of partisan Sudoku is interesting because it reduces to impartial Sudoku--the game sum using binary values delivers the same result as outcomes under normal or misère play:

In the even Sudoku game, second player can always mirror and the result will always be a 0.  In the even game, player one can use the complement to mirror, and the outcome will always be a 1.

In the basic forms of partisan Sudoku (non-reduced) the elements have value corresponding to their labels, which correspond to the ordinal values in any set comprising a row, column or region.

Using the complement to mirror in the odd game does not assure victory, because the game sum is rooted in values base-$m^n$, where $(m^n)^n$ describes the matrix.  (See the link above for different types of outcomes in the basic partisan forms of Sudoku.  A distinction of partisan Sudoku games is that the outcomes are ratios.)

Furthermore, in the even-Sudoku partisan game, although player two can always mirror, player two will only mirror if they perceive player one to have placed optimally in regard to the un-reduced value of the placed element.

This is, of course, only where the game tree is still intractable.  Sudoku games are wildly intractable at the outset, but, like all natively finite games, collapse into a determined state.  (This is similar to a [Wave Function Collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse)).

The [solution to the impartial game](https://mathoverflow.net/a/297884/105789) is the first serious mathematical work on Sudoku games I am aware of.  I have little doubt this is a subject that will be rigorously studied, not least because [the Sudoku puzzle](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/428729/mathematics-of-sudoku-leads-to-richter-scale-of-puzzle-hardness/), and [Latin squares in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Applications), have proven to be so useful.

From the abstract to *[The Chaos Within Sudoku](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00725?WT.mc_id=FBK_SciReports)*:

> The mathematical structure of Sudoku puzzles is akin to hard constraint satisfaction problems lying at the basis of many applications, including protein folding and the ground-state problem of glassy spin systems. Via an exact mapping of Sudoku into a deterministic, continuous-time dynamical system, here we show that the difficulty of Sudoku translates into transient chaotic behavior exhibited by this system. We also show that the escape rate κ, an invariant of transient chaos, provides a scalar measure of the puzzle's hardness that correlates well with human difficulty ratings. Accordingly, η = −log10 κ can be used to define a “Richter”-type scale for puzzle hardness, with easy puzzles having 0 < η ≤ 1, medium ones 1 < η ≤ 2, hard with 2 < η ≤ 3 and ultra-hard with η > 3. To our best knowledge, there are no known puzzles with η > 4.

Comment: For more information on how certain games such as Domineering have partisan and impartial forms, and how they can be analogous, see: [Positions of value *2 in Generalized Domineering and Chess](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/fg6/fg6.pdf).